# Drop-down inside a <div> which is inside a <fieldset> while duplicating is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a piece of code which lets me duplicate the div=tableOfTables, but when i duplicate I can make the whole fieldset id="group_1" duplicated with unique id.
The issue occurs when i keep the

```
<select>
    ...code...
</select>
```

block, it is not allowing to duplicate the fieldset.
Is that against the CSS rules to put a dropdown inside a fieldset, which requires duplication?

```
<form>
    <fieldset id="group_1">
        <legend>Group# 1</legend>Duplicate text
        <div id="tableOfTables" class="formfield">
            <table id="dataTableInner">Group# from table</table>
            <tr>
                <td>hi</td>
                <td>
                <select>
                    <option value="item1">Equals</option>
                    <option value="item2">Less Than</option>
                    <option value="item3">Greater Than</option>
                </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>

$('#add_one_more_group').click(function (event) {

    // Clone the first fieldset
    var item = $('fieldset[id^="group_"]:first').clone();

    // Search for the greatest existing fieldset ID
    var max_index = 0;
    $('form').children('fieldset[id^="group_"]').each(function () {

        var pattern = new RegExp("^group_([0-9]*)$");
        var matchArray = pattern.exec($(this).attr('id'));
        if (matchArray !== null && matchArray.length == 2) {
            max_index = Math.max(max_index, matchArray[1]);
        }
    });
```

I can see that a dropdown option is working fine inside the fieldset, but the whole fieldset cannot be duplicated.

Here's a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raja777m/SG3QR/17/)**.

Comment: You've closed your table tag, this will break your markup. Move the </table> to under the last </tr>

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, but it didn't help much.
I assume this might help a bit more:
http://jsfiddle.net/raja777m/SG3QR/15/

Comment: I think there might be some mistake with my JS, not giving proper references to the IDs, but I need an extra set of eyes.
Appreciate you helping me